# Is there a replacement for "CLR SPY" Com-Interop "spy" program

Tags: windows, com

This utility used to be on gotdotnet.

http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/Standards/DeveloperGeneral/netTools.aspx#CLRSpy

But now it's gone.

Is there a replacement for "spying" on com-interop between running programs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
http://www.nektra.com/products/com-spy-console

to see COM object's activity.

Comment: The link is not working, It returns 404 Not Found.